# How can I return the text of a cross-reference when I have a reference to the heading, all inside VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to be able to return the full paragraph text of a cross-reference in VBA, when I already have a cross-reference to the paragraph heading. I need to do this without modifying the original field code.

For example, if I create a cross-reference to a paragraph heading, the field code will look something like `{ REF _Ref136248344 \r \h}` and will return something like `1.23`. I can manually convert this to the text of the paragraph itself by removing the `\r`, which will then give `the full text of the paragraph I'm cross-referencing`.

**What I've tried**

I've tried using the Field object in VBA to get the original reference (e.g. `{ REF _Ref136248344 \r \h}` ), then running `Replace$(strCode, "\r", "")` to take the `\r` out and give the field code I need (in this example. `{ REF _Ref136248344 \h}` , but I can't find any way of then running this new field code in VBA to get the result. Is it possible to make a new field object, apply this string to `Field.Code` and then get `Field.Code.Result`?

This is my current code, which doesn't work:

```
Public Function getTextFromCrossRef()
With Selection
        If .Fields.Count > 0 Then
            Dim myField As Field, crossRefText As String, crossRefResult As String
            Set myField = .Fields(1)
            crossRefText = "Cross-reference " & myField.result & " is:"
            crossRefResult = getFullTextFromFieldCode(myField)
                 
            modCallUserforms.callDisplayMesageNotModal "Result of cross-reference", crossRefText, crossRefResult
        Else
            MsgBox "No cross-references found in selection"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function convertFieldCodeFromHeadingToText(strCode As String) As String
    convertFieldCodeFromHeadingToText = Replace$(strCode, "\r", "")
End Function

'This was my attempt to apply a field code to a new field - this doesn't work
Public Function getFullTextFromFieldCode(inputField As Field) As String
    Dim newField As Field
    Dim inputFieldCode As String
    Dim result As String
    
    inputFieldCode = convertFieldCodeFromHeadingToText(inputField.Code)
    With newField
        .Code = inputFieldCode
    End With
    result = newField.result
End Function
```

Possibly another option is to use the field code to get back to the original reference point, then copy from there?

I can't copy and paste the new field code back into the original document.

I'd prefer to avoid having to create a new Word document, the idea is for this to be quick and support new lookups dynamically.

**End result**

I do a lot of contract reviews, which necessitate scrolling backwards and forwards to multiple references, which are often quite complex. I'm building a small userform that will return the text of a cross-reference on screen, next to the place it is referenced, to aid usability and speed up review.

**Edit**

I tried creating a new field and editing it directly, but this also modifies the old field at the same time. I assume Word is using the _Ref to identify them. At the moment, it doesn't look like it's possible to do what I want.

```
Public Function getFullTextFromFieldCode(inputField As Field) As String
    Dim newField As Field
    Dim result As String
    Dim newFieldCodeText As String
    
    Set newField = inputField
    newFieldCodeText = inputField.Code.text
    newFieldCodeText = Replace$(newFieldCodeText, "\r", "")
    newField.Code.text = newFieldCodeText
    newField.Update 'This line also changes inputField to match newField
    result = newField.result.text

    getFullTextFromFieldCode = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `newField` is simply an object variable with the datatype of Field. It does not exist as a field, so it cannot have a result.

The simplest way of achieving what you want is to temporarily change the field code, update the field to get the result, and change it back again.

```
Public Function getTextFromCrossRef()
    With Selection
        If .Fields.Count > 0 Then
            Dim myField As Field, crossRefText As String, crossRefResult As String, fldCode As String
            Set myField = .Fields(1)
            crossRefText = "Cross-reference " & myField.result & " is:"
            crossRefResult = getFullTextFromFieldCode(myField)
            modCallUserforms.callDisplayMesageNotModal "Result of cross-reference", crossRefText, crossRefResult
        Else
            MsgBox "No cross-references found in selection"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Private Function getFullTextFromFieldCode(inputField As Field) As String
    Dim origFieldCode As String, editedFieldCode As String
    
    origFieldCode = inputField.Code
    editedFieldCode = Replace$(inputField.Code, "\r", "")
    With inputField
        .Code = editedFieldCode
        .Update
        getFullTextFromFieldCode = .result
        .Code = origFieldCode
        .Update
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this the only way? I can’t create a Field object only in memory and work with that? It will be a shame if so…

Comment: An object variable is merely a memory address set aside to store an object. A field would only be stored by using the `Set` statement to point to an existing field in the document. Until that happens the variable is utterly empty.

Comment: I was thinking more like Excel, where I could (for example) create a Range object in memory and work entirely in VBA, only interacting and changing the sheet at the end. Similarly, here I’d like to instantiate a Field object and do everything in VBA if possible, without interacting with Word.

Comment: Hi, see my latest edit. Changing a new field also changes the existing one...

Comment: @Jonathan - Word is not Excel. I have already provided you the solution.

Comment: Of course, but I don't think it's unreasonable to wonder if elements of it work the same, given they are both part of the same Office suite. Regardless, thank you for your help, it's saved me a lot of frustration trying to get it to work!

Comment: @Jonathan - they may be part of the same suite but they don't share developers. Even when features are shared across the suite, e.g. themes, they are implemented differently.